# Select concatenated value where two values match across the whole table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My apologies for such a simple question, I am usually relatively OK when applying SQL queries (thanks to StackOverflow) in my work however this one has me stumped.

I have an MS SQL table named [UKStaffList] with the following information in it...

```
EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName  | ManagedBy
----------------------------------------------
1001       | Robert    | Anderson  | 1004
1002       | Chris     | Thompson  | 1004
1003       | Mary      | Wright    | 1004
1004       | Andrew    | Denton    | 1005
1005       | Susan     | Rogers    | 1005
1006       | Michael   | Stevens   | 1007
1007       | Alice     | Lee       | 1005
1008       | John      | Clarke    | 1007
```

I'd like to create a view that allows me to see the name of the `Manager` as well as the other information already in the table. The code below shows the final outcome that i'd like to see...

```
EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName  | ManagedBy | Manager
--------------------------------------------------------------
1001       | Robert    | Anderson  | 1004      | Andrew Denton
1002       | Chris     | Thompson  | 1004      | Andrew Denton
1003       | Mary      | Wright    | 1004      | Andrew Denton
1004       | Andrew    | Denton    | 1005      | Susan Rogers
1005       | Susan     | Rogers    | 1005      | Susan Rogers
1006       | Michael   | Stevens   | 1007      | Alice Lee
1007       | Alice     | Lee       | 1005      | Susan Rogers
1008       | John      | Clarke    | 1007      | Alice Lee
```

I have tried the following query...

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, ManagedBy,
       CASE WHEN ManagedByID = EmployeeID THEN CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName)
            ELSE 'N/A'
       END AS Manager
FROM UKStaffList
```

However this only shows me the 5th row, where `Susan` `Rogers` is the manager of themselves and all other rows are N/A. From what I can see, the query is only looking for values where the `ManagedBy` and `EmployeeID` match on the same row.

```
EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName  | ManagedBy | Manager
--------------------------------------------------------------
1001       | Robert    | Anderson  | 1004      | N/A
1002       | Chris     | Thompson  | 1004      | N/A
1003       | Mary      | Wright    | 1004      | N/A
1004       | Andrew    | Denton    | 1005      | N/A
1005       | Susan     | Rogers    | 1005      | Susan Rogers
1006       | Michael   | Stevens   | 1007      | N/A
1007       | Alice     | Lee       | 1005      | N/A
1008       | John      | Clarke    | 1007      | N/A
```

Ideally, I need to have a query that will show the managers name as a concatenation of their first and last names in a separate column where the `ManagedBy` column references their `EmployeeID`.

One caveat is that I need to keep all of the data in this one table.
I think I may need a nested query in this, but I'm not sure where to start.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong and provide some guidance?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to self join the table.

Answer (score 1):

As @jarlh commented you just have to join your table with itself, in order to join every employee with its manager.

Remember that when joining a table with itself you have to use aliases : they have the same columns so you will need to use aliases to differentiate the columns from the employees and the managers.

Like this:

```
SELECT Staff.EmployeeID, Staff.FirstName, Staff.LastName, Staff.ManagedBy,
       CONCAT(Managers.FirstName, ' ', Managers.LastName) AS Manager
FROM UKStaffList as Staff
     LEFT JOIN UKStaffList as Managers on Managers.EmployeeID = Staff.ManagedBy
```